# Gulp less with images

Tags: less, gulp

Is there a way for gulp-less (or some other tool) to take the paths to images that are referenced in the .less/.css file and put the files to the destination folder?

Right now when I install a node module, I @import the css file from /node_modules/... directory to my main .less file and it will be included in the bundle, but the images that come with the module are still located under /node_modules/... folder which I don't plan to deploy so using a relative URL would be pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using [bower](http://bower.io/) to split your dev dependencies (handled by `npm`, non-deployed stuff) and front-end libs (handled by `bower`, deployed stuff).

Using a `.bowerrc` like this, you can tell where to save the libs in you projects structure:

```
{
  "directory": "./<your-public-folder>/libs"
}
```

Comment: I see, I guess that's the way to do it. I was wondering why there are 2 systems, npm and bower, seemingly same. Thanks!